# Test behavior in vs2012 unit test framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, stub

Below is my test:

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void GetSubscribers()
    {

        stubSubscriptionMng.GetModelSubscribersInt32String = (mgr, i) => new List<IModel>() { modelStub };
        var dispatcher = UnitySingleton.Instance.UnityContainer.Resolve<Dispatcher>();
        IDispatchingMessage message = new DispatchingMessage(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "MessageName", "MessageVal", 1);
        dispatcher.Publish(message);

    }
```

This is the method being tested:

```
  if (message.UniverseId > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.EntityId) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.MessageName))
            {
                //the modelMgr will forword the the relevant Data to the relevant Models
                IList<IModel> models = subscriptionService.GetModelSubscribers(message.UniverseId, message.MessageName);
                Parallel.ForEach(models, (model) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        model.Update(message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ResourceManager.Instance.Logger.LogException(ex);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Each model is being called with the `void Update()` method. Is there a way to verify this behavior? To verify the method had been called?
Something equivalent to `Expect()` and `verifyAllExpectations()` in [Rhino mocks](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%203.5.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)?

---

I found a workaround solution in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390422/how-can-i-verify-that-a-microsoft-fakes-beta-stub-shim-was-called-like-assert).

Comment: found a workaround in the following post:
[solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390422/how-can-i-verify-that-a-microsoft-fakes-beta-stub-shim-was-called-like-assert

Comment: Is there a constraint that doesn't allow you to use Rhino Mocks?

Comment: Yes. we wanted to base out testing on pure VS2012 testing api...